# HikariCP behavior on connection close if transaction was not explicitly committed/rolled-back?

Tags: hikaricp

I am migrating from BoneCP to HikariCP. In BoneCP there is the following option:

```
# If true, issue a reset (rollback) on connection close in case client forgot it.
resetConnectionOnClose=true
```

What is HikariCP's behavior in this scenario, when the connection is closed without explicitly committing/rolling-back the transaction? I did not find the equivalent configuration option.

Thank you,
Gab

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer in `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection`'s code source. In the `close()` method there is the following code:

```
if (this.isCommitStateDirty && !this.isAutoCommit) {
    this.delegate.rollback();
    this.lastAccess = ClockSource.currentTime();
    LOGGER.debug("{} - Executed rollback on connection {} due to dirty commit state on close().", this.poolEntry.getPoolName(), this.delegate);
}
```

thus if you do not have the `autoCommit` config option enabled and you did not explicitly commit/rollback then it rollsback for you.

Comment: And what happens when autoCommit is true?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check but basically [HikariPool](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/45912ebb570ff9d54c010da61d1f2c26cc5cd39b/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java) call `close` method  for [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) so it seems to be depending on the driver implementation

> It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

Comment: I know and agree with the above statement, but there are cases where you are not the one to call close() (e.g. it is called during error management in some frameworks, etc.). BoneCP's connection proxy checks if this option is enabled and forces a rollback. In cases as described above this is convenient to set/use because as you state this is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Gabriel you can verify in hikari group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hikari-cp